# Does the EXP Boosting DLC Dish affect Request EXP Rewards

Tags: etrian-odyssey-untold-2

One of the DLC for *Etrian Odyssey Untold 2* came with a repeatable request for getting food that's used for ad a dish which boosts EXP Gain.

I am wondering, does this EXP Boost affect the EXP i gain from redeeming a Request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does.

Using "The honeyed lure" quest i completed this, saved and went to redeem it without the EXP Boost and got 11250 EXP as a reward. after reloading i prepared the EXP Boost dish in the cafe and the EXP reward was 33750 which is 3x the original reward.

this also applies to Missions from the Duke's Palace. redeeming "In pursuit of the Salamander" got me 33860 EXP before preparing the dish and after i got 101580 EXP, again a x3 increase.